# how to enable google map marker

Tags: html, api

below is the jquery for display the map on my html page now i want to show the marker on the particular spot on this map then how can i enable it .please help me to solve this problem.

[image: Result images of running map]

```
tjq(document).ready(function() {

            tjq('a[href="#map-tab"]').on('shown.bs.tab', function (e) {
                var center = panorama.getPosition();
                google.maps.event.trigger(map, "resize");
                map.setCenter(center);
            });

            var map = null;
            var panorama = null;
            var fenway = new google.maps.LatLng(48.855702, 2.292577);
            var mapOptions = {
                center: fenway,
                zoom: 12
            };

            var panoramaOptions = {
                position: fenway,
                pov: {
                    heading: 34,
                    pitch: 10
                }
            };
            function initialize() {
                tjq("#map-tab").height(tjq("#hotel-main-content").width() * 0.6);
                map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-tab'), mapOptions);
                panorama = new google.maps.StreetViewPanorama(document.getElementById('steet-view-tab'), panoramaOptions);
                map.setStreetView(panorama);
            }
            google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);




html code for showing the map 


     <div id="map-tab" class="tab-pane fade">

                                        </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

you just have to add new variable for marker inside init function:

```
var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
      position: myLatLng,
      map: map,
      title: 'Hello World!'
    });
```

Reference : [google maps Javascript API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/marker-simple)

Comment: i already put this script but now working .please provide any other soluation.